# Select in multi-index dataframe with lists

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that I have a dataframe df with multi-index ['Date', 'Letter', 'Number'] with date from 2012-01-01 to present with daily interval, letter from A-Z and number from 1-9.

I want to select values from this df by giving 3 lists: eg. [2015-01-01 : 2020-01-01], [A, B, D, G, X], [1,3,5,7,9].

How would I be able to do that?

I know that you can use df.xs eg. df.xs(('2015-01-01', 'A', '3'), levels=[0,1,2]) to get single elements from each index. But I want a method where I can give 3 lists instead.

Comment: Please directly provide a DataFrame constructor, this is easier to reproduce and more explicit than a description ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Example index and dataframe:
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    pd.date_range("2015", "2023", freq="Y"),
    list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"),
    list(range(1, 10))
], names=["Date", "Letter", "Number"])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "data": np.random.rand(1872)
}, index=idx)

# Solution:
out = df.loc[
    pd.IndexSlice[
        "2015-01-01":"2020-01-01",
        ["A", "B", "D", "G", "X"],
        [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
    ]
]
```

out:

```
                              data
Date       Letter Number
2015-12-31 A      1       0.724715
                  3       0.995834
                  5       0.330251
                  7       0.338611
                  9       0.189550
...                            ...
2019-12-31 X      1       0.329585
                  3       0.658865
                  5       0.719360
                  7       0.445797
                  9       0.149293

[125 rows x 1 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your data has named index, you can use `query` like this

```
df.query('(Date in @list_date) & (Letter in @list_letter) & (Number in @list_number)')
```

where `list_date`, `list_letter`, and `list_number` are your list variables.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.repeat(np.arange(4), 3),
                   'b': np.tile(list('abc'), 4),
                   'c': np.arange(12)}).set_index(['a','b'])

lv1, lv2 = [1,2], ['b','c']

df.query('(a in @lv1) & (b in @lv2)')
```

Output:

```
     c
a b   
1 b  4
  c  5
2 b  7
  c  8
```